# QT4.8 - Implement highlight to QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I am looking for a way to implement a highlighter for the QLineEdit widget.

I am using a QLineEdit to store a a path variable in my application, and I would to highlight environment variables.

Something like this:
**${MY_ENVVAR}**/foo/bar/myfile

Practically I would to have something like the QHightligher class.

Comment: You may have to do something like this: http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_create_a_one-line_qtextedit

Answer (score -1):

1. Subclass `QSyntaxHighliger`
2. Write your own `highlightBlock()` method
3. Detect in your string this specific text which must be colored (you can do this for example by regular expression `QRegExp`) and use `setFormat()` method to paint string from x to x+n with some color

Helpful link: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#highlightBlock

I never used highliter with `QLineEdit` before, so it can be impossible. But we can simply attach highliter to the `QTextEdit`. So we should create lineEdit from textEdit, there are many examples in web how to do that.

For example (I use code given by `hyde` with small additions.)

TextEdit.h

```
#ifndef TEXTEDIT_H
#define TEXTEDIT_H

#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QCompleter>

#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QStyleOption>
#include <QApplication>


class TextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
        explicit TextEdit(QWidget *parent = 0)
        {
                setTabChangesFocus(true);
                setWordWrapMode(QTextOption::NoWrap);
                setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
                setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
                setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
                setFixedHeight(sizeHint().height());
        }

    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)

    {

            if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Return || event->key() == Qt::Key_Enter)

                    event->ignore();

            else

                    QTextEdit::keyPressEvent(event);

    }
        QSize sizeHint() const
        {
                QFontMetrics fm(font());
                int h = qMax(fm.height(), 14) + 4;
                int w = fm.width(QLatin1Char('x')) * 17 + 4;
                QStyleOptionFrameV2 opt;
                opt.initFrom(this);
                return (style()->sizeFromContents(QStyle::CT_LineEdit, &opt, QSize(w, h).
                        expandedTo(QApplication::globalStrut()), this));
        }
};

#endif // TEXTEDIT_H
```

Usage (in the main.cpp)

```
#include "textedit.h"

//...

    TextEdit *t = new TextEdit;
    t->show();
    new Highlighter(t->document());
```

Highlighter constructor as example

```
Highlighter::Highlighter(QTextDocument *parent)
    : QSyntaxHighlighter(parent)

{

}
```

Comment: How should this ne used with `QLineEdit`?

Comment: @hyde I never used highliter with QLineEdit before, so it can be impossible. But we can simply attach highliter to the QTextEdit. So we should create lineEdit from textEdit, there are many examples in web how to do that.

Comment: You should add that to the answer. As it is now, it's wrong (as far as I know), especially considering last paragraph of the question: OP knows of QHighlighter and wants something like it.